# How do I perform the summation of a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data entries like so:

[image]

that I'm trying to run through several summation functions, such as

[image]

My current solution in this case is creating another column in which I exponent every x value, and then another for the product between x^6 and y, before finally summing that column.

Is there a better way of doing this in Excel?

Comment: Yes, there is a better solution. But what your are trying to do? Summation what? For your given data what would be result? Are you facing any problem to get that desired result?

Comment: @Harun24HR The current problem that I have is that I need to run 12 summation functions through a solver, and I need to do that for 6 different data sets. My current approach works, but it also requires creating two tables per function.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12^6)*(B2:B12))
```

Comment: From what I can tell, it seems like the A2:A12^6 is erroneous

Comment: What is the expected result for the sample data?

Comment: Apart from the missing minus, this formula looks fine. @gamehen please provide the result for your example. I got `-1,70758E+16` with the mentioned formula.

Comment: @gamehen as `SUMPRODUCT` behaves like an array-formula, there is no erroneous behavior. First power of 6 is applied to all elements of `A2:A16`, then get multiplied with `B2:B12` and finally the results get summed up. You could also use `-SUM(POWER(A2:A12,6)*B2:B12)` but you have to press **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** to close the formula, so `sumproduct` is the more handy one.